# Where do I start diagnosing a RAID drive that won't come up?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, diagnostic, raid-5

I've had this [Cavalry 4TB RAID drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0013P8QAM) connected via eSATA to a Win2003 box for a year or two, and it's not coming up any more (can't see it in Explorer, or in disk management). I've also tried connecting it directly to a Win7 laptop and no dice.

It's configured as RAID-5. I'm guessing either one of the drives has gone bad, or there's a problem with the Cavalry hardware.

Where do I start diagnosing this?

Comment: If it's Raid5. One of the drives dying would not cause it to vanish. You would just have a degraded (or some other term for it) array. That's the point of Raid-5 to allow for single disk fails. If 2 drives have gone down then you're in the doo-doo

Answer (score 0):

Can you telnet to the device? Documention seems hard to find.  Do you have the install CD with manuals? Are there any error lights or unusual light activity (or lack of lights) on any drives?

Is the RAID configuration manager available/installed?  The manager may point you to an issue

Comment: It normally shows 4 lights; sometimes it shows none, sometimes it shows one.

Comment: The RAID manager doesn't see anything. I wouldn't know where to start telnetting to the device.